# Magento 2 - Refill cart after refused from payment page

Tags: magento2, cart

I want cart to be refilled after customer return back to my controller with some error. Here is my controller code, I can access `increment_id` here

```
public function execute()
{
    if(array_key_exists("req_reference_number",$_POST)) {
        $increment_id = $_POST["req_reference_number"];
        $status = $_POST["decision"];
        $message = $_POST["message"];
        $order = $this->order->loadByIncrementId($increment_id);
        if ($status == "CANCEL") {
            //Cancel previous order
            $this->statusCanceled($order);

            /*************
            ** Want to refill cart here
            **************/

            //redirect to checkout page with restoring cart
            $redirectionUrl = $this->url->getUrl('checkout/cart/');
            $this->response->create()->setRedirect($redirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
        }
    }else{
        $redirectionUrl = $this->url->getUrl('/');
        $this->response->create()->setRedirect($redirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
    }
    die();
}
```

My question is, how can I refill my cart using order increment id that is placed and cancelled.

I had used this code but it's not working, my cart is still empty

```
$quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
$quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null);
$this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
$this->session->replaceQuote($quote);
```

Comment: Take a look at the "Reorder" button logic in customer order history. It does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to reactivate the old quote, delete payment and reserved order id and reuse it. In that way you preserve also address data.
I don't know your context, but with injecting the mentioned object the approach should work.

```
//inject cart model and checkout session model to your controller
protected $cart;
protected $checkoutSession;

public function __construct(
     //...
     \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
     \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
)
{
    //...
    $this->cart = $cart;
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
}

$quote = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory')->create()->load($order->getQuoteId());

$quote->setReservedOrderId(null);
$quote->setIsActive(true);
$quote->removePayment();
$quote->save();

//replace the quote to the checkout session (I guess this is the better way)
$this->checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);

//OR add quote to cart
$this->cart->setQuote($quote);

//if your last order is still in the session (getLastRealOrder() returns order data) you can achieve what you need with this one line without loading the order:
$this->checkoutSession->restoreQuote();
```

Comment: Tried your code, but my cart is still empty :(

Comment: Load your cart model and add the quote `$cart->setQuote($quote)`.

Comment: I have added the code that I was using to fill up cart. please have a look in question. I highly appreciate your support

Comment: OK, I have updated the code try adding the quote to the checkout session first since the cart is taking the quote from there

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the code above, the correct method in the checkout session is `replaceQuote`, I had a mistake in my code

Comment: Tried your code, from the look of this I thought it will work, but my cart is still empty :(

Comment: That's really strange. Can you debug the code? For example see if you get a quote from the order that way? And after replaceing the quote in the session can you please log `$this->cart->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();` or some other quote method?

Comment: Issue resolved. The problem was with the redirection. Payment page redirecting to non www url, and after adding to session it was redirection to www. That's why session was destroyed everytime and cart was empty. Now it is fixed. Thanks for your support HelgeB :)

Comment: I have used the restoreQuote(), the quote data is getting restored properly but In my case on restoreing quote data  it is always placing abandoned cart email.